# How to indicate Service Changed with ESP32 BLE with Arduino Framework

Tags: ios, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32, gatt

I'm developing a firmware using ESP32 and Arduino Framework.
I'm using BLE with the "official" library, this device will be connected to a smartphone.
There is a peculiarity,

## I already done everything but there is a problem

I add a new Service **RUNTIME**... on Android I managed to be able to refresh the services list correctly... but on iOS it **does not work**... so doing my research I found out that seems that I have to send an **Indication** on the **Service Changed** characteristic (0x2A05) inside the **Generic Attribute** Service (0x1801) to inform the smartphone that the GATT structure has changed, so it have to get new structure from the esp32 instead of the cache (?).

## The question are

What is the right way to inform the smartphone through the Service Changed characteristic?
This should be automatically done by the BLE library?